# How do you override @JsonSerialize() on an object you don't have the source for?

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have a class that is in a .jar that I can't modify.

It has an `@JsonSerialize()` annotation on the class.

```
@JsonSerialize(using = SomeClassSerializer.class)
@JsonDeserialize(using = SomceClassDeserializer.class)
public class SomeClass { /* ommitted */ }
```

Now I need to run a custom serializer on this class to output completely different JSON.

Here is what I have tried:

```
final SomeClass sc = new SomeClass();
// setup ommitted
final ObjectMapper m = new ObjectMapper();
final SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule();
module.addSerializer(SomeClass.class, new CustomClassSerializer());
m.registerModule(module);
m.enable(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT);
m.writer().writeValue(System.out, sc);
```

The problem is I get the default annotated `SomeClassSerializer` output and not the `CustomClassSerializer` output.

#### How to I tell the `ObjectMapper` to ignore the annotations?

Comment: Serialize the object and rewrite the JSON.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Solution

```
final ObjectMapper m = new ObjectMapper();
m.disable(MapperFeature.USE_ANNOTATIONS);
```

After much digging through the JavaDocs I found this solution, which appears to be the most idiomatic way of doing it.

Comment: Wait, that seems to ease! :D

Comment: I think that MixIn solution is much better because it changes configuration only for one class. `MapperFeature.USE_ANNOTATIONS` feature turns off all annotation for all classes - it can cause an issue in another place of the app.

Comment: no it doesn't, it only turns it off for this specific instance of the `ObjectMapper` which inside a Junit test is only processing what I need it to process, or inside a specific REST call needs to transform a specific object differently.

Comment: Thanks! saved me a LOT of time

Answer (score 4):

You can use [the Jackson mixin annotations](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonMixInAnnotations) to override the original class serializer. Here is an example:

```
public class JacksonMixInOverride {
    public static class BeanSerializer extends JsonSerializer<Bean> {

        @Override
        public void serialize(Bean value, JsonGenerator jgen, SerializerProvider provider)
                throws IOException {
            jgen.writeString("normal");
        }
    }
    public static class CustomBeanSerializer extends JsonSerializer<Bean> {

        @Override
        public void serialize(Bean value, JsonGenerator jgen, SerializerProvider provider)
                throws IOException {
            jgen.writeString("custom");
        }
    }

    @JsonSerialize(using = BeanSerializer.class)
    public static class Bean {

    }
    @JsonSerialize(using = CustomBeanSerializer.class)
    public static interface BeanMixIn {

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonProcessingException {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.addMixInAnnotations(Bean.class, BeanMixIn.class);
        System.out.println(mapper.writeValueAsString(new Bean()));
    }
}
```

Output:

```
"custom"
```

Comment: I wanted propose the same solution! Good hint.

Comment: @MichałZiober I answered faster and got down-voted saving you from loosing some reputation score :-)